"I would say" VS "I would have said" (in the context of giving one's opinion about something)
On TV, a woman who has spent years to make herself look like a Barbie doll is telling about her story, how and why she has been doing it. It turns out that she actually had painful days years ago, losing family members, etc. At one point, the TV presenter says:

It's really interesting hearing you say that. I didn't know this, the story about your sister and stuff like that, but it's like covering up pain, isn't it? A little bit of covering up of pain, I would have said.

ITV-britain's oldest barbie doll (see: 5:17-5:28)
The expression "..... I would have said" caught my attention. I know the expression "I would say" is used when giving your opinion about something, which is exactly what the TV presenter is doing.
But why does she say ".....I would have said," instead of "..... I would say"?

The two mean the same thing. I would say that I would have said is a Britishism. I don’t believe I have heard it used on this (the western) side of the Atlantic.

The logician in me feels that the two forms shouldn’t have the same meaning—the have said version being past tense. But, last I looked, I am not The Ultimate Decider of how anyone should speak.

@PaulTanenbaum: I'd say that according to this usage chart, there's no reason to suppose Brits are any more likely than Americans to go in for this unwarranted prolixity. I suggest your assumption derives from two false premises. - 1) BrE retains older usages more doggedly than AmE, and 2) This particular example was more common in the past.

I really don't know why she should use the past tense here, unless it's a subconscious match with "I didn't know...".

...bear in mind that I would say is itself just an "indirect, roundabout" way of saying I say. There's no literal meaning to the alternatives - they're just ways of "distancing" the speaker from his assertion, thus potentially "softening" it, in case someone else disagrees.

imho it's exactly the same "distancing" involved in [A. "I just wanted to let you know that ..."
B. "I just want to let you know that ..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/50999/why-do-people-use-past-tense-here) The Past Tense implies "hesitation, deference". Both Past Tense and "conditional" would have this effect.

@FumbleFingers, thanks that makes sense.

@KateBunting, thanks that makes sense, too.

I don't think this is a Britishism at all. Used in AmE too.

@FumbleFingers, although empirical data is typically a good thing, it must be used with care. Do we know that your n-gram search caught those uses and only those uses where the two phrases are essentially identical in meaning? If not, then a weak signal may lie buried within the noise of a lot of non-relevant uses.

@Lambie, okay. Two Americans have differing subjective senses. I was intrigued by yours. As they say, “your mileage may vary.”

@PaulTanenbaum I have heard "I would have said" in AmE when you eschew disagreeing with someone outrightly. It's very PC. Think again: Have you really never heard it? :) [Every time I see your name, I think of Christmas and log fires. ]

@PaulTanenbaum: I don't need those charts to tell me what I've learned over a lifetime of using English. They're only there to help convince other people (primarily learners, who wouldn't otherwise have much idea what's going on). But if you're not convinced we can just agree to differ. I'm not really in the business of teaching native Anglophones about their own language.

(@Lambie, I went to the University of Maryland, where every hour on the hour, the chapel bells played my song (check out the tune of—what was then—our state song, Maryland, My Maryland.))

@FumbleFingers, my only point was that Google’s n-gram results must, like all quantitative data, be used with care, regardless for whom one is using them.

Voting to close because the answer to the duplicate is much better.


... it's like, it's covering up pain, isn't it? a little bit covering up of pain, I would have said.

There’s no grammatical justification to use would have said, which should be applicable only for post-event comments.  To illustrate, if I were the TV presenter,  I would’ve said I would say.
